# Next N numbers from an SQL sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, mariadb

Let's say I have an SQL sequence `seq`. Can I fetch `N` next numbers from it in one statement (`N` is variable, so I cannot just fetch `N` columns)?

I know that in Oracle database I can use the following query:

```
select seq.nextval from dual connect by level <= ?
```

which returns (e.g.):

```
NEXTVAL
15
16
17
```

I'm particularly interested in doing the same in MariaDB, but something using standard SQL would be even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use recursive CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT 1 AS v
  UNION ALL
  SELECT v+1
  FROM cte
  WHERE v < 3   -- here goes limit
)
SELECT seq.nextval
FROM cte;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=58fa4496daa65db081ae70394b5a5b8f)**

---

Another approach is to set `INCREMENT BY 3`. Then you will get first number and could deduce next two values on application level.

## EDIT:

> *Question is tagged to Oracle and above solution will not work in oracle. We can achieve recursion in Oracle not by this way rather making multiple CTE.*

Oracle supports recursive CTE as well.

```
WITH cte(v) AS (
  SELECT 1 FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT v+1
  FROM cte
  WHERE v < 3
)
SELECT seq.NEXTVAL
FROM cte;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=244ad1acf2aca5294f90394f23ba9ebe)**

Comment: Thank you. Certainly more complicated than for Oracle, but works and can be parameterized as I need.

Comment: @doublep To be fair it is standard way of doing recursive queries. Oracle `CONNECT BY` is proprietary. CTE will work on Oracle too: **[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=244ad1acf2aca5294f90394f23ba9ebe)**

Comment: Sure, I know that.

Comment: Question is tagged to Oracle and above solution will not work in oracle. We can achieve recursion in Oracle not by this way rather making multiple CTE. However this might work for other DB lile mariadb and postgre

Comment: @XING Two things: `I'm particularly interested in doing the same in MariaDB, but something using standard SQL would be even better.` It will work on MariaDB. OP has working solution on Oracle. Second https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=244ad1acf2aca5294f90394f23ba9ebe

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be using MariaDB, use it's "sequence" thingie.  Something like this:

```
SELECT @base + n FROM seq_1_to_999999 WHERE n <= @N;
```

The pseudo-table has more rows than you need, but the `WHERE` clause limits it to your @ variable.

Sequences like this were available long before CTEs were.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the purpose of fetching n number of sequence and wasting sequence. Anyway if you want like that then you can use any table which have your required number of records and use the below sql and get the sequence 
Select seq.nextval from  limit ?

note: number of records in that table should be greater than or equal that the given limit number